# UITextField cursor animated top to down then text also being animated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am working registration form in iOS application. There several textfields such as name,email,city etc. when the textfield started editing cursor appearing like animated. Cursor slowly coming from top to down after typing the letter its moving from left to right slowly.I need to stop this unwanted animation. I am using TPKeyboardAvoiding scrollview to scroll the view when keyboard popup. I checked it without TPKeyboardAvoiding but same thing happening.[image]

Comment: What is the superview of the UITextField?

Comment: uiviewcontroler only the superview for uitextfield

Comment: I have gone through searching with tpkeyboard keyword, but no related link anywhere

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered same issue, after debugging I found that this weird animation is happening because of

```
- (void)TPKeyboardAvoiding_keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification {
    //...
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
    //...
}

- (void)TPKeyboardAvoiding_keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)notification {
    //...
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
    //...
}
```

I am able to fix this issue by removing `[self layoutIfNeeded];` method call. I don't know if this solution affects anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the animation comes from the `TPKeyboardAvoiding` library. I also have the same screen in my app (Registration) and use the same library. However I put my textfields inside a custom `UITableViewCell` and have a `UITableView` for the registration. This way there is less code and its cleaner. I disable scrolling on the `UITableView` so that the `UIScrollView` will receive the touches correctly.

I'd suggest doing it that way.

Comment: I removed the TPKeyboardAvoiding, but still no change

Comment: Have you tried this on an actual device to see if it does the same thing?

Comment: thanks for the answer @tander, problem is not because of tpkeyboard. i forgot to remove the uiviewanimations. I used uiviewanimations as a alternative of tpkeyboard

Answer (score 0):

Call `superview.layoutIfNeeded()` (or `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`, depending on your code context) before you begin changing any animatable properties in the view. This allows the superview to finish its own layout changes (if any) before you make your own layout changes and commit your animations. (This may be difficult to track down if an external library is applying its own animations.)

Comment: Why the downvote?? See "Animating Changes Made by Auto Layout" in Apple's Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutolayoutPG.pdf